# Measured voltage is lower than set on bench power supply

Tags: voltage, short-circuit

I'm trying to identify the issue with my portable monitor. While testing it I noticed a weird (at least for me) thing that I can't understand.

I set voltage on my power supply to be exactly 7.2V. When I measure it on the power supply terminals it indeed shows 7.2V. Now when it's measured on the battery connector (where I inject the voltage) it measures only 6.8V.

Does it mean there is a voltage leak to the ground? I'd expect my power supply to show 6.8V on the screen but it shows 7.2V as set.

Comment: Wires all have resistance. If a current is flowing through them, there will be a voltage drop. Do you know the current and the wire gauge?

Comment: Voltage doesn't leak. Current does.

Comment: You fail to mention what is very important: **how much current is flowing**? When a current is flowing, a **voltage drop** will occur across **every resistance** in the circuit where that current is flowing. Such resistances are **always present** in cables and in connectors.

Comment: That's indeed a voltage drop across the cables (from V = I R), as others have pointed out. If you are using long and thin cables then the drop can be more significant if the current increases *(e.g. you can see the same thing when you charge your smartphone with your wall charger: charger's output is 5.1V at the output jack but your phone's jack sees 4.6V)*.

Comment: How much current battery is taking? @Maciej

Comment: The circuit is taking ~400mA. I've checked it and you guys are right, the voltage is lower due to resistance of the wires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you measure the 7.2 V on the PS output while the battery is connected? There could be a significant voltage drop across the cables and connectors between your PS and the battery.

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed a voltage drop due to wires resistance.